# Rewriting conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Say we have random variables $B,B^1,\dots,B^k\in\mathbb{R}$. Then is it true that
$$
\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]
=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^k]|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}\Big].
$$
If not, then is there any way to write $f_{k-1}=\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]$ in terms of $f_{k}=\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^{k}]$. I'm trying to see if there is any connection between the two. I was thinking maybe
$$
\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}]
=\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B|B^1,\dots,B^k]|B^{k}\Big],
$$
but this seems a bit strange to me since I don't know if law of total expectation can be applied when you are conditioning on other variables $B^1,\dots,B^{k-1}$. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: Thanks. I realize this is just a generalization of the law of total expectation. Note: The statement that is true is the first displayed equation, and not the second one.